# Consuming SOAP service using Axis2 from JSF app. Problems with Maven/Axis configuration

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, azure, apache-axis

I have web application build using JSF, Tomcat as app container, Google Guice for injection and Azure as storage. Everything is working so far, web app is serving pages etc.

I needed to consume SOAP service so I generated class from WSDL using WSDL2JAVA (from Axis2 distribution) and I added dependencies to my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I need only to **consume** SOAP, I am not building a SOAP server. Unfortunately after including Maven dependencies and stub class I keep getting errors when I try to connect to my web app:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null InputStream is not a valid argument
    com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:614)
    com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:317)

I don't have any code related to SOAP (other than unused stub class), I don't do any outgoing requests.

Question is: does Axis install anything in it's default configuration which can interfere with other mechanisms of web application (class finding, injection, servlets etc.)?